# Using code splitting in a MVP GWT project

Tags: gwt, mvp

In a project i'm working on, we follow the MVP structure but we do not use any particular framework like GTWP. For such situations where theres no code splitting 'out-of-the-box' what are some best practices to adopt in the utilization of this tool? (Where to split the code, other considerations, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to go through GWT Developer's Guide Code splitting . It talks some best practices.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting